# C# Connection mysql with self signed

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection, self-signed

Is self signed certificate disrupting connection to mysql?
I already give action crud in data and grant access to administration.

but the connection still got error.

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

my team connection like this:

```
Catalog=devbaf;User Id=userclient;password=client123
```

connection code:

```
  try
        {
            string constring = "SERVER=123.45.678.9;DATABASE=devbaf;User Id=backendsystem;PASSWORD=1q2w3e4r5t;";
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constring))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM users"))
                {
                    using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            gvtest.DataSource = dt;
                            gvtest.DataBind();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Response.Write(e.Message.ToString());
        }
```

explanation problem:

I make a database in local server, so my friend can access to it to insert data. but when he make a connection script it wont connect to my database but can connect to server. He already tries to move some file to the server and it works,but the connection to database wont connect. i don't have an experience for this coz im php programmer not c# programmer. hope my explanation is clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have found your error message like trying to connect the host but in your connection string is missing the MySQL server name or host address.  I hope if you add the MySQL hostname or server address to your connection. it will fix your issue.

you can try this

```
string connectionString ="SERVER=servername; DATABASE=databasename; User Id=userid; PASSWORD=password;";
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: thanks for the answer, i already give the explanation and the snippet code also.. @SanthakumarMunuswamy